# I/O Exception (java.net.SocketException)

Tags: java, ssl, netbeans, https, get

I have been attempting to make a GET request to an HTTPS site. For testing purposes, I'm directing my code to https://httpbin.org/ip as directed by an example I found elsewhere on StackOverflow. I generated a keystore, and the code successfully loads that file and properly (as far as I can tell) creates the CloseableHttpClient.

The code executes until I see the "Executing request" message in my output window. Then it hangs for 60 seconds (standard timeout for HttpGet) and throws the following error:

> Feb 24, 2016 5:01:58 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
>   INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://httpbin.org:443: Connection reset
>   Feb 24, 2016 5:01:58 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
>   INFO: Retrying request to {s}->https:httpbin.org:443

I've tried generating a new keystore, as well as different SSLSocket settings (like ignoring all certificates), but I always get the same error. I'm convinced that I'm making a mistake in generating key/certificate, but I can't seem to pinpoint where. Full code below.

Edit: I'm using Netbeans.

```
    // Trust own CA and all self-signed certs
    SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom()
            .loadTrustMaterial(new File("src/keystore.jks"), "password".toCharArray(),
                    new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
            .build();
    // Allow TLSv1 protocol only
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
            sslcontext,
            new String[] { "TLSv1" },
            null,
            SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier());
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf)
            .build();
    try {

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://httpbin.org/ip");


        System.out.println("Executing request " + httpget.getRequestLine());

        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

        try {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
            EntityUtils.consume(entity);
        } finally {
            response.close();
        }
    } finally {
        httpclient.close();
    }
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? I'm facing a similar issue.

Comment: @kregnax  did you solve this problem. I am facing a similar issue. please see this question I posted - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68831811/apache-commons-dbcp-i-o-exception-during-execution-of-validationquery